# Grab specific text from string

Tags: java

I am  needing to grab specific text in the following string:

"{client_unique_identifier=cdakLs1W7oI+M3z+CzFv1lEUkaY=, cldbid=2086, client_nickname=sman}"

What I need is it to return their nickname cldbid which is "2086" as a int

Comment: Is this JSON?  If it is, have you considered using a JSON processing library (such as GSON) instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
static int getNumber(){
    int result = 0;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cldbid=(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("client_unique_identifier=cdakLs1W7oI+M3z+CzFv1lEUkaY=, cldbid=2086, client_nickname=sman");
    if(m.find()){
        result = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is always in the format you listed.

```
//property = 'cldbid='
public int getUserProperty(String property, String data) {
    int start = data.indexOf(property)+property.length();
    int end = data.indexOf(',', start);

    return Integer.parseInt(data.substring(start, end));
}
```

However; I would implement this as a regex/pattern matching like previous poster suggested.  Tutorial here.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/